# How to create deluge script of my c# code

Tags: c#, zoho, zoho-deluge

fI am beginner and I just wanted to create a function that call the external api and display the response

This is my code

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://fapi.myfci.com/graphql");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <apikey>");
var content = new StringContent("{\"query\":\"\\n{ \\n  getLoanInformation\\n        {\\n            loanAccount\\n            achStatus\\n            amortizationType\\n            appraiserDate\\n            appraiserMarketValue\\n            appTimeStamp\\n            aRMOptionActive\\n            article7\\n            assignment\\n            boardingDate\\n            borrowerAddress\\n            borrowerCity\\n            borrowerEmail\\n            borrowerFax\\n            borrowerFirstName\\n            borrowerFullName\\n            borrowerHomePhone\\n            borrowerLastName\\n            borrowerMI\\n            borrowerMobilePhone\\n            borrowerState\\n            borrowerWorkPhone\\n            borrowerZip\\n            chargesAdjustment\\n            deferredLateCharges\\n            deferredPrinBal\\n            deferredUnpaidCharges\\n            deferredUnpaidInt\\n            draws\\n            ficoScore\\n            firstPaymentDate\\n            floatCapForNegAmort\\n            floatCapForPayment\\n            floatCeiling\\n            floatDaysAfterPymtChange\\n            floatDaysAfterRateChange\\n            floatEnabledPymtAdj\\n            floatEnableFirstRateCap\\n            floatEnableLastRecast\\n            floatEnableRecast\\n            floatFirstRateMaxCap\\n            floatFirstRateMinCap\\n            floatFloor\\n            floatFreqPymtChange\\n            floatFreqRateChange\\n            floatFreqRecast\\n            floatIndex\\n            floatLastRecast\\n            floatMargin\\n            floatNextAdjPayment\\n            floatNextAdjRate\\n            floatNextAdjRecast\\n            floatPeriodicMaxCap\\n            floatPeriodicMinCap\\n            floatRoundMethod\\n            floatRoundRateFactor\\n            floatSendNotice\\n            floatStopRecast\\n            funds\\n            impoundBalance\\n            iNFIndexARMUid\\n            investAssetNumber\\n            lateChargesDays\\n            lateChargesPct\\n            lenderAccount\\n            lienPosition\\n            loanAccount\\n            loanChargesAccruedInterest\\n            loanChargesPrincipal\\n            maturityDate\\n            nextDueDate\\n            noteRate\\n            noteType\\n            occupancyStatus\\n            originalBalance\\n            originationDate\\n            paidOffDate\\n            paidToDate\\n            payment\\n            paymentImpound\\n            paymentReserve\\n            poffAcrruedInterest\\n            poffAcurredLateCharges\\n            poffFromBorrower\\n            poffFromEscrow\\n            poffFromSuspense\\n            poffPaidLateCharges\\n            poffPrepayPenalty\\n            poffPrincipalBalance\\n            poffTotal\\n            poffUnpaidCharges\\n            poffUnpaidInterest\\n            poffUnpaidLateCharges\\n            prevAccount\\n            principalBalance\\n            principalWaived\\n            propertyAPN\\n            propertyCity\\n            propertyState\\n            propertyStreet\\n            propertytype\\n            propertyZip\\n            purpose\\n            rateType\\n            restrictedFunds\\n            suspenseBalance\\n            section32\\n            seniorLoanAmount\\n            status\\n            statusLender\\n            thomasMap\\n            unearnedDiscount\\n            unpaidCharges\\n            unpaidInterest\\n            unpaidInterestWaived\\n            unpaidLateCharges\\n            unpaidLateChargesWaived\\n         }\\n}\",\"variables\":{}}", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Can Any one help me creating the deluge script for the above code

I have tried but it is not working .

```
function callAndDisplayAPI() {
endpoint = "https://fapi.myfci.com/graphql";

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer <apikey>"};

// Define API request body
requestBody = "{\"query\":\"\\n{ \\n getLoanInformation\\n    {\\n      loanAccount\\n      achStatus\\n      amortizationType\\n      appraiserDate\\n      appraiserMarketValue\\n      appTimeStamp\\n      aRMOptionActive\\n      article7\\n      assignment\\n      boardingDate\\n      borrowerAddress\\n      borrowerCity\\n      borrowerEmail\\n      borrowerFax\\n      borrowerFirstName\\n      borrowerFullName\\n      borrowerHomePhone\\n      borrowerLastName\\n      borrowerMI\\n      borrowerMobilePhone\\n      borrowerState\\n      borrowerWorkPhone\\n      borrowerZip\\n      chargesAdjustment\\n      deferredLateCharges\\n      deferredPrinBal\\n      deferredUnpaidCharges\\n      deferredUnpaidInt\\n      draws\\n      ficoScore\\n      firstPaymentDate\\n      floatCapForNegAmort\\n      floatCapForPayment\\n      floatCeiling\\n      floatDaysAfterPymtChange\\n      floatDaysAfterRateChange\\n      floatEnabledPymtAdj\\n      floatEnableFirstRateCap\\n      floatEnableLastRecast\\n      floatEnableRecast\\n      floatFirstRateMaxCap\\n      floatFirstRateMinCap\\n      floatFloor\\n      floatFreqPymtChange\\n      floatFreqRateChange\\n      floatFreqRecast\\n      floatIndex\\n      floatLastRecast\\n      floatMargin\\n      floatNextAdjPayment\\n      floatNextAdjRate\\n      floatNextAdjRecast\\n      floatPeriodicMaxCap\\n      floatPeriodicMinCap\\n      floatRoundMethod\\n      floatRoundRateFactor\\n      floatSendNotice\\n      floatStopRecast\\n      funds\\n      impoundBalance\\n      iNFIndexARMUid\\n      investAssetNumber\\n      lateChargesDays\\n      lateChargesPct\\n      lenderAccount\\n      lienPosition\\n      loanAccount\\n      loanChargesAccruedInterest\\n      loanChargesPrincipal\\n      maturityDate\\n      nextDueDate\\n      noteRate\\n      noteType\\n      occupancyStatus\\n      originalBalance\\n      originationDate\\n      paidOffDate\\n      paidToDate\\n      payment\\n      paymentImpound\\n      paymentReserve\\n      poffAcrruedInterest\\n      poffAcurredLateCharges\\n      poffFromBorrower\\n      poffFromEscrow\\n      poffFromSuspense\\n      poffPaidLateCharges\\n      poffPrepayPenalty\\n      poffPrincipalBalance\\n      poffTotal\\n      poffUnpaidCharges\\n      poffUnpaidInterest\\n      poffUnpaidLateCharges\\n      prevAccount\\n      principalBalance\\n      principalWaived\\n      propertyAPN\\n      propertyCity\\n      propertyState\\n      propertyStreet\\n      propertytype\\n      propertyZip\\n      purpose\\n      rateType\\n      restrictedFunds\\n      suspenseBalance\\n      section32\\n      seniorLoanAmount\\n      status\\n      statusLender\\n      thomasMap\\n      unearnedDiscount\\n      unpaidCharges\\n      unpaidInterest\\n      unpaidInterestWaived\\n      unpaidLateCharges\\n      unpaidLateChargesWaived\\n     }\\n}\",\"variables\":{}}";

response = invokeurl
[
    url: endpoint
    type: POST
    parameters: requestBody
    headers: headers
];

// Check if API call was successful
if (response.get("responsecode") == 200) {
    
    info response.get("response");
} else {
    
    info "Error occurred while calling API: " + response.get("response");
}
```

}

```
callAndDisplayAPI();
```

Comment: What is the error that is thrown?